# Magic number in optimal redo size query in Oracle 9i

Tags: optimization, transaction-log, oracle-9i

I got this query from [this blog post](http://www.gokhanatil.com/2009/08/optimum-size-of-the-online-redo-log-files.html) to determine the optimal online redo log size in pre-Oracle10 databases.

I'm stuck with Oracle 9i for that particular instannce for reasons beyond my pay grade and in this version the view `V$INSTANCE_RECOVERY` lacks the `OPTIMAL_LOGFILE_SIZE` column):

```sql
SELECT
      (SELECT ROUND(AVG(BYTES) / 1024 / 1024, 2) FROM V$LOG) AS "Redo size (MB)",
      ROUND((20 / AVERAGE_PERIOD) * (SELECT AVG(BYTES) FROM V$LOG) / 1024 / 1024, 2) AS "Recommended Size (MB)"
FROM 
     (
                SELECT AVG((NEXT_TIME - FIRST_TIME) * 24 * 60) AS AVERAGE_PERIOD
                FROM V$ARCHIVED_LOG
                WHERE FIRST_TIME > SYSDATE - 3
                AND TO_CHAR(FIRST_TIME, 'HH24:MI') BETWEEN
                '00:00' AND '23:59'
      );
```

I indented the query to understand in better but I fail to understand why the author uses the magic number `20`.

**Can someone tell me why the `20` and whether this query can be otherwise improved?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First sentence in the blog post:

> The Oracle Database Performance Tuning Guide recommends switching logs
>   at most once every **twenty** minutes.

Official source:

[Sizing Redo Log Files](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/build_db.htm#10302)

> It is not possible to provide a specific size recommendation for redo
>   log files, but redo log files in the range of a hundred megabytes to a
>   few gigabytes are considered reasonable. Size your online redo log
>   files according to the amount of redo your system generates. A rough
>   guide is to switch logs at most once every **twenty** minutes.